# Update PostgresSQL column with computed data from the same table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql

I need to update values in a PostgreSQL table based on information from the same table.

For example the table look like this

**Before Update**:

| index | shop_id | tire_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Winter | Null |
| 1 | 0 | Summer | Null |
| 2 | 0 | Winter | Null |
| 3 | 0 | Winter | Null |
| 4 | 1 | Summer | Null |
| 5 | 1 | Winter | Null |

---

**After Update**:

| index | shop_id | tire_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Winter | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | Summer | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | Winter | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | Winter | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | Summer | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | Winter | 1 |

For this example the table contains types of tires connected the the shop table via shop_id.
The count column should contain the number of the same tire types on the same shop_id.

From example above we can see that the number of the type Winter at shop_id = 0 is 3 so each row
with Winter type should have the number 3 in count column.

How can this be done with SQL ? Or with Python Pandas  DataFrame on an existent DataFrame (that will be inserted on an existent PostgresSQL table) ?

P.S. The table schema can't be changed. The preferred solution is with Pandas but it is ok with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [30]: df['count'] = df.groupby(['shop_id', 'tire_type'])['count'].transform('count')

In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   index  shop_id tire_type  count
0      0        0    Winter      3
1      1        0    Summer      1
2      2        0    Winter      3
3      3        0    Winter      3
4      4        1    Summer      1
5      5        1    Winter      1
```

Then write this `df` back to `Postgres` using `df.to_sql`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by tire_type, shop_id)
from t;
```

If you need to update the value, then you can use aggregation in an `update` statement:

```
update t
    set count = tt.cnt
    from (select tire_type, shop_id, count(*) as cnt
          from t
          group by tire_type, shop_id
         ) tt
    where t.tire_type = tt.tire_type and t.shop_id = tt.shop_id
```